# Windows Media Player Skin Repeat Button

Tags: wms

I am trying to get the code for the repeat button to work. The shuffle is working, but the repeat does not. Any help would be great! The button is part of the main background. The .wms file is below. I am using .png files for my images. Not really sure what I should all add on to here.

```
<THEME>
<VIEW
    clippingColor = "#780E85"
    backgroundImage = "wmpSkin2.png"
    titleBar = "False" 
    width="925"
    height="502"
    backgroundColor="none"
    transparencycolor="#780E85"
    scriptFile="skin.js"
    onLoad="OnOpenStateChange();">

    <player PlayState_onchage="OnOpenStateChange();"
        OpenState_onchange="OnOpenStateChange();"
        modeChange="OnOpenStateChange();"
    >
    </player>

    <BUTTONGROUP
        mappingImage = "wmpSkinMapping.png"
        hoverImage = "wmpSkinHover2.png">

        <!-- Control buttons -->
        <PLAYELEMENT mappingColor = "#000080"
            upToolTip = "Play" />
        <PAUSEELEMENT mappingColor = "#0000FF"
            upToolTip = "Pause" />
        <STOPELEMENT mappingColor = "#FFFF00"
            upToolTip = "Stop" />
        <BUTTONELEMENT mappingColor = "#FF00FF"
            upToolTip = "Next"
            onClick="jscript:player.controls.next()"
            cursor="system"
            enable="wmpenabled.player.controls.next" />
        <BUTTONELEMENT mappingColor = "#00FF00"
            upToolTip = "Previous"
            onClick="jscript:player.controls.previous()"
            cursor="system"
            enable="wmpenabled.player.controls.next" />

        <!-- Minimize, Full Mode, Exit Buttons -->
        <BUTTONELEMENT mappingColor = "#808000"
            upToolTip = "Minimize"
            onClick="view.minimize();" />
        <BUTTONELEMENT mappingColor = "#FFA500"
            upToolTip = "Return to Full Mode"
            onClick="view.returnToMediaCenter();" />
        <BUTTONELEMENT mappingColor = "#008000"
            upToolTip = "Close"
            onClick="JScript: view.close();" />

        <!-- Shuffle and Repeat -->
        <BUTTONELEMENT id="btnShuffle"
                mappingColor="#008080"
                upToolTip="Turn Shuffle On"
                downToolTip="Turn Shuffle Off"
                onClick="player.settings.setMode('shuffle',down);"
                down="wmpprop:player.settings.getMode('shuffle')"
                sticky="true"
            >
        </BUTTONELEMENT>
        <BUTTONELEMENT id="btnRepeat"
            mappingColor="#800080"
            onclick="jscript:player.settings.setMode('loop',down);"
            upTooltip="Enable Repeat" 
            downTooltip="Disable Repeat"
            down="wmpprop:player.settings.getMode('loop')" 
            sticky="true">
        </BUTTONELEMENT>
    </BUTTONGROUP>

    <seekSlider zindex="2"
        left="230" top="141"
        backgroundImage="sleekbar.png"
        thumbImage="sleekbtn.png"
        thumbHoverImage="sleekbtnHover.png"
        transparencyColor="#780E85"
        borderSize="5"
        useForegroundProgress="false"
        >
    </seekSlider>
    <text id="metadata"
        left="240"
        top="169"
        width="275"
        fontSize="6"
        fontSmoothing="true"
        fontFace="Arial"
        foregroundColor="#003EAA"
        scrollingDelay="50"
        scrollingAmount="1"
        justification="Center"
        scrolling="true"
        toolTip=""
        passThrough="true"
        fontStyle="normal">
    </text>
    <text id="metadata2"
        left="240"
        top="169"
        width="275"
        fontSize="6"
        fontSmoothing="true"
        fontFace="Arial"
        foregroundColor="#003EAA"
        scrollingDelay="50"
        scrollingAmount="1"
        justification="Center"
        scrolling="true"
        toolTip=""
        passThrough="true"
        fontStyle="normal">
    </text>

</VIEW>
</THEME>
```

Comment: This is like a trip to the past - wmp & winamp skins, ah. Anyway, couldn't be the problem that you used in btnShuffle `onClick="player.settings.setMode('shuffle',down);"` and in btnRepeat `jscript:player.settings.setMode('loop',down);` ?

Comment: I tried adding jscript to the onclick for btnShuffle and still does the same thing. I'm trying to follow Microsoft's online instructions, and lets face it... its not very good. I have never done anything like this before.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, however, I must agree. Always hated Microsoft for this and few other reasons. Try to download a skin that work, extract the code if it's possible and compare with your `repeat` to make it work.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I feel so stupid.  It does work but not the way I wanted it to. I was hoping to repeat a single song but it repeats the whole playlist.

Comment: Hehe, nice one! Try to use `loopone` or something like this if the one-song mode is not in documentation or find a code that works as I've mentioned.